# Difference between Call and Observable Response in Retrofit interface

Tags: android, interface, observable, retrofit

I don't understand meaning 2 way this (`Observable` and `Call`.)

```
@GET("/users")
fun getAll(): Observable<List<User>>

@GET("/users")
fun getById(): Call<List<User>>
```

I want to understand it, please.
Very Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using retrofit without RxJava you can use call. If you are using RxJava you should use Observable.